# Devise, CanCan, Rolify could not find table 'users_roles'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, roles, rolify

I have been following [this guide](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial) to use and install Rolify with Devise and CanCan. But when I try to add a role to a user in the console using `user.add_role :admin` I get the following error which states that the `users_roles` table could not be found.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: This dynamic method is deprecated. Please use e.g. Post.find_or_create_by(name: 'foo') instead. (called from irb_binding at (irb):7)
Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."name" = 'admin' AND "roles"."resource_type" IS NULL AND "roles"."resource_id" IS NULL ORDER BY "roles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'roles_users'
```

Here are my files:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  validates_presence_of :name
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

end
```

ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  scopify
```

end

Yes, I have migrated using `rake db:migrate`. I'm using rails 4.0.2, so where do I go from here??

Thank you!

Comment: The `rolify` method handles the associations for you; so you are able to omit the HABTM roles.

Comment: Duh! Had that line from when I tried doing it with HABTM. Thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming you ran the generator before migrating correct? `rails g rolify Role User`

Comment: `rails g rolify:role` is what I ran. I had a User model from Devise. It worked this time.